# Undefined references within equations

Tags: cross-referencing, pstricks, fancyhdr, labels, ntheorem

So my problem is that there seams to be a clash between something in my preamble and the `\label{}` and `\ref{}` commands. When I do references within my definition environment it all goes smoothly, but whenever I try to label something within an equation environment, the reference becomes undefined, regardless of whether the equation is located within a definition/theorem environment or just within the document.

Here is my preamble along with an example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{paralist}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb, amsfonts}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,svgnames,table]{xcolor}
\usepackage[framed, thmmarks, standard]{ntheorem}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{pstricks}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\rfoot{page \thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}

\numberwithin{equation}{section}

\definecolor{lightgray}{gray}{0.94}

\theoremseparator{:}
\theoremstyle{nonumberplain}
\theoremheaderfont{\itshape}
\theorembodyfont{\normalfont}
\theoremsymbol{\nolinebreak[1]\hspace*{.5em plus 1fill}\ensuremath{\Box}}
\newtheorem{myproof}{Proof}

\theoremstyle{break}
\theoremheaderfont{\normalfont\bfseries}\theorembodyfont{\slshape}
\theoremseparator{}
\theoremsymbol{}
\shadecolor{lightgray}
\newshadedtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[section]

\theoremstyle{break}
\theoremheaderfont{\normalfont\bfseries}\theorembodyfont{\slshape}
\theoremseparator{}
\theoremsymbol{}
\shadecolor{lightgray}
\newshadedtheorem{mydef}{Definition}[section]

\begin{document}

\section{First section}

\begin{mydef}[Something]
\label{def:something}
We will now define something. It has a property:
\begin{equation}
\label{eq:first}
x+y=z
\end{equation}
\end{mydef}

Now I want to reference it. according to definition 
\ref{def:something} we have.. 
If we look at equation \ref{eq:first}...

Also we have another equation:
\begin{equation}
\label{eq:second}
z>0
\end{equation}

I also want to talk about equation \ref{eq:second}

\end{document}
```

Can anybody see where the issue might be? 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the documentation of `ntheorem`, section 3.2.1, you should add the option `amsmath` together with `thmmarks` if you load the `amsmath` package:

```
\usepackage[amsmath,thmmarks]{ntheorem}
```

Full example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{paralist}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb, amsfonts}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,svgnames,table]{xcolor}
\usepackage[amsmath,framed, thmmarks, standard]{ntheorem}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{pstricks}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\rfoot{page \thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}

\numberwithin{equation}{section}

\definecolor{lightgray}{gray}{0.94}

\theoremseparator{:}
\theoremstyle{nonumberplain}
\theoremheaderfont{\itshape}
\theorembodyfont{\normalfont}
\theoremsymbol{\nolinebreak[1]\hspace*{.5em plus 1fill}\ensuremath{\Box}}
\newtheorem{myproof}{Proof}

\theoremstyle{break}
\theoremheaderfont{\normalfont\bfseries}\theorembodyfont{\slshape}
\theoremseparator{}
\theoremsymbol{}
\shadecolor{lightgray}
\newshadedtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[section]

\theoremstyle{break}
\theoremheaderfont{\normalfont\bfseries}\theorembodyfont{\slshape}
\theoremseparator{}
\theoremsymbol{}
\shadecolor{lightgray}
\newshadedtheorem{mydef}{Definition}[section]

\begin{document}

\section{First section}

\begin{mydef}[Something]
\label{def:something}
We will now define something. It has a property:
\begin{equation}
\label{eq:first}
x+y=z
\end{equation}
\end{mydef}

Now I want to reference it. according to definition 
\ref{def:something} we have.. 
If we look at equation \ref{eq:first}...

Also we have another equation:
\begin{equation}
\label{eq:second}
z>0
\end{equation}

I also want to talk about equation \ref{eq:second}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Btw. totally unrelated, but how do you make it render the output in tex?

Comment: @ErikOlesen I take a snapshot of the screen and upload it.

Comment: Right sure. Grazie mille :)

Answer (score 2):

Using a more simplified example you can see it's the `thmmarks` option that causes the problem

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}


\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage
%[thmmarks]
{ntheorem}

\numberwithin{equation}{section}

\newtheorem{mydef}{Definition}[section]

\begin{document}

\section{First section}

\begin{mydef}[Something]
\label{def:something}
We will now define something. It has a property:
\begin{equation}
\label{eq:first}
x+y=z
\end{equation}
\end{mydef}

Now I want to reference it. according to definition 
\ref{def:something} we have.. 
If we look at equation \ref{eq:first}...

Also we have another equation:
\begin{equation}
\label{eq:second}
z>0
\end{equation}

I also want to talk about equation \ref{eq:second}

\end{document}
```

Haven't traced exactly where the label goes yet, it doesn't get written to the aux file at all if that option is used.

Comment: we ran into a superficially related problem today in an article for an ams journal.  the `\ref` was inside an equation, and although the label was in the aux file, the `\ref` would always come out as **??**.  we finally packed the `\ref` in an `\mbox` (`\hbox` and `\text` also worked) and it was resolved.  not the same thing, since in the present case the `\label` is getting "lost" rather than just not being seen, but worth remembering.  i think the problem here may be similar to what happens to footnote texts in section headings.